# Jquery form validation incremental phone number field name

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-validate

I have a form that is dynamically loaded by server side scripts.
It loads rows of user's details.

I am using jquery validate plugin to validate but it will only validate the first row/first user.

each rows input fields have the sane name. name="PhoneNumber" . I could add the name to be name="PhoneNumber1"...name="PhoneNumber2" etc.

My question is, is it possible to iterate through the rows of the form and validate each PhoneNumber "at the same time"?

Comment: I don't know how this validate plugin works, but you do something like `$('input[name="PhoneNumber"]').each(function(){ $(this).validate('phone-rules'); });` or, of course, add the event listener to validate

Answer (score 0):

You can validate it as below

```
var phoneInvalid = false;
var phoneRegEx = /^[2-9]\d{2}-\d{3}-\d{4}$/;

$("form").find("input[name*=PhoneNumber]").each(function(){
  if(!phoneRegEx.test($(this).val())){
     phoneInvalid = true;
     return false;
  }
});
```

//Now you can use `phoneInvalid` to show the appropriate error message.